# Convert cvs to mercurial

Tags: mercurial, cvs

I'm trying to convert a CVS repository to mercurial but can't get it to work.

I start with a clean checkout:

```
cvs -d :sspi;username=xxx;hostname=yyy.local:/cvsrepos checkout repo
```

Which works fine

I then do:

```
hg convert .
```

But it fails with:

```
assuming destination .-hg
initializing destination .-hg repository
connecting to :sspi;username=xxx;hostname=yyy.local:/cvsrepos
abort: unexpected response from CVS server (expected "Valid-requests", but got 'E cvs [server aborted]: Root :sspi;username=xxx;hostname=yyy.local:/cvsrepos must be an absolute pathname\n')
```

I'm running cvsnt on windows 7

**Edit:**
Investigated this a bit more and it seems like mercurial starts a local server `cvs server` and then communicates with that instance instead of the remote server.

I base this on the following observations:

1. I created a cvs.bat file that sends the command line arguments to a file. The file shows the argument "server".
2. process monitor shows that hg.exe tries to open the file
   `C:\cvstest\:sspi;username=xxx;hostname=yyy.local:\cvsrepos` which of course fails.

Can it be that hg does not understand the sspi connection string?

**Edit 2:**

Not a solution but I found a workaround: Copy the complete remote repository to my machine and:

```
cvs -d :local:\localcopyofrepo checkout repo
hg convert repo
```

Everything worked fine

Comment: That's what I attempted to say in my answer, you could mark it as answered though that, or add your own answer and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the error message is telling you to use an absolute pathname to the repository, try using

```
hg convert <full_path_including_drive>
```

rather than the `.` path on a checked out sandbox of your CVS repository.  You could also try specifying the repository type in the `convert` command by adding `-s cvs` to the command, the result would look something like this:

```
hg convert -s cvs C:\sandbox\cvsrepos
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using [ConvertExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_CVS).  Can you try `hg convert` from the parent folder and specify the folder name, instead of `.` and see if it works?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ConvertExtension ("hgext.convert=" in .hgrc). Specifying source and/or target folder makes no difference.