# Convert CVS to Hg on Windows

Tags: mercurial, cvs

I'm trying to convert our company's CVS to Mercurial but so far without success. Remote file history should be retained.

I tried the conversion tools described on [RepositoryConversion - Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RepositoryConversion#CVS)

### Convert extension

```
e:\Hg>hg convert -s CVS H:\Cvs
assuming destination cvs-hg
initializing destination cvs-hg repository
abort: CVS: invalid source repository type
```

What's going on!?

### cvs2hg

Looks very promising, but errors out at the last moment.

```
python cvs2hg -v --encoding=UTF8 --hgrepos=e:/Hg h:/Cvs
```

Result after 10 minutes and 9 miles of text:

```
----- pass 14 (SortSymbolOpeningsClosingsPass) -----
Sorting symbolic name source revisions...
Done
Time for pass14 (SortSymbolOpeningsClosingsPass): 0.150 seconds.
Deleting cvs2svn-tmp\statistics-13.pck
Deleting cvs2svn-tmp\symbolic-names.txt
----- pass 15 (IndexSymbolsPass) -----
Determining offsets for all symbolic names...
  VERSION_0_22
  VERSION_0_18
  VERSION_0_11
  VERSION_0_9
  VERSION_0_5
  VERSION_0_1
Done.
Time for pass15 (IndexSymbolsPass): 0.130 seconds.
Deleting cvs2svn-tmp\statistics-14.pck
----- pass 16 (OutputPass) -----
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cvs2hg", line 91, in <module>
    hg_main(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]), sys.argv[1:])
  File "c:\Portable progs\cvs2svn-19b322d42b1f\cvs2svn_lib\main.py", line 135, in hg_main
    main(progname, run_options, pass_manager)
  File "c:\Portable progs\cvs2svn-19b322d42b1f\cvs2svn_lib\main.py", line 96, in main
    pass_manager.run(run_options)
  File "c:\Portable progs\cvs2svn-19b322d42b1f\cvs2svn_lib\pass_manager.py", line 181, in run
    the_pass.run(run_options, stats_keeper)
  File "c:\Portable progs\cvs2svn-19b322d42b1f\cvs2svn_lib\passes.py", line 1771, in run
    svn_commit.output(Ctx().output_option)
  File "c:\Portable progs\cvs2svn-19b322d42b1f\cvs2svn_lib\svn_commit.py", line 238, in output
    output_option.process_primary_commit(self)
  File "c:\Portable progs\cvs2svn-19b322d42b1f\cvs2svn_lib\hg_output_option.py", line 291, in process_primary_commit
    svn_commit, [parent1, parent2], filenames, getfilectx, lod)
  File "c:\Portable progs\cvs2svn-19b322d42b1f\cvs2svn_lib\hg_output_option.py", line 715, in _commit_primary
    return self._commit(svn_commit, parents, filenames, getfilectx, lod)
  File "c:\Portable progs\cvs2svn-19b322d42b1f\cvs2svn_lib\hg_output_option.py", line 733, in _commit
    return self._commit_memctx(mctx)
  File "c:\Portable progs\cvs2svn-19b322d42b1f\cvs2svn_lib\hg_output_option.py", line 739, in _commit_memctx
    node = self.repo.commitctx(mctx)
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 63, in wrapper
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 1399, in commitctx
  File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 1193, in _filecommit
  File "mercurial\filelog.pyo", line 76, in cmp
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

### Tailor, fromcvs

Initially blocked by link rot, but after Googling a lot, turn out to be Linux-only tools (?). I do have cygwin but I never had any good experiences compiling source distributions.

### hg-cvs-import

Link rot too, and can't find anything. Moreover about the last three tools, I read on [Would you migrate from cvs to svn or directly to git or hg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153122/would-you-migrate-from-cvs-to-svn-or-directly-to-git-or-hg): "The Tailor extension, hg-cvs-import, fromcvs seems to be old code and aren't maintained any more."

---

I also tried the trick on [Convert cvs to mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131690/convert-cvs-to-mercurial), even though it probably only retains local file history, but got the same result as in my first try.

Any other tools I somehow missed? Maybe a user-friendly application for Windows?

Comment: What version of hg are you on? It might make sense to rollback to the current version that aligns with the tool you're using.

Comment: Is `H:\Cvs` working directory of CVS and is it fresh checkout?

Comment: Mercurial 3.1.1. Just saw a newer version, testing it out now. `H:\Cvs` is the server repository, not a checkout.

Comment: Same result. Any idea if the script requires a specific older version of Hg? (going by date, I guess 1.8.1)

Comment: **READ** about convert extension requirements **carefully**!!! Source of CVS-code **MUST BE** 1) CVS-checkout 2) performed by the same version of CVS CLI-tool, which you have at the moment of conversion. **RTFM!!!**

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded with **cvs2hg** and **Mercurial 2.0 source** (not a newer version)

- Download the Mercurial 2.0 source,
- Copy the `Mercurial`folder (found inside the `Mercurial-2.0` folder) to the `cvs2svn` folder,
- Go into `cvs2svn/Mercurial/pure`,
- Copy the contents to `cvs2svn/Mercurial`,
- Execute `python cvs2hg`

Comment: it MUST be version 2.0. Tried it with the newest version (3.x) and it didn't work...